# Adding rows for missing months and Fill na values with last value in a partition Python

Tags: python, pandas, explode, fill

I have a pandas dataframe and I need to fill NULL values with the last value on a partition.
Specifically, for each "id" and "month", I need to create and explode last "value" on subsequent months.

***Example of my dataset:***

| id | month | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | London |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 | Paris |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | New York |
| 3 | 2023-02-01 | Paris |
| 4 | 2023-03-01 | NULL |

***My desidered output (Exploding the values up to April 2023):***

| id | month | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | London |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 | Paris |
| 1 | 2023-03-01 | Paris |
| 1 | 2023-04-01 | Paris |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | New York |
| 2 | 2023-02-01 | New York |
| 2 | 2023-03-01 | New York |
| 2 | 2023-04-01 | New York |
| 3 | 2023-02-01 | Paris |
| 3 | 2023-03-01 | Paris |
| 3 | 2023-04-01 | Paris |
| 4 | 2023-03-01 | NULL |
| 4 | 2023-04-01 | NULL |

Thank u!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using reshaping as a rectangular intermediate with [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)/[`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'])

out = (df
    .pivot(index='id', columns='month', values='value')
    .reindex(columns=pd.date_range('2023-01-01', '2023-04-01', freq='MS').rename('month'))
    .ffill(axis=1)
    .stack().reset_index(name='value')
)
```

Or with a MultiIndex and [`groupby.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html):

```
out = (df
   .set_index(['id', 'month'])
   .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['id'].unique(),
                                        pd.date_range('2023-01-01', '2023-04-01', freq='MS')],
                                      names=['id', 'month']
                                      ))
   .groupby(level=0).ffill().dropna().reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
    id      month     value
0    1 2023-01-01    London
1    1 2023-02-01     Paris
2    1 2023-03-01     Paris
3    1 2023-04-01     Paris
4    2 2023-01-01  New York
5    2 2023-02-01  New York
6    2 2023-03-01  New York
7    2 2023-04-01  New York
8    3 2023-02-01     Paris
9    3 2023-03-01     Paris
10   3 2023-04-01     Paris
```

##### keeping/filling original NaNs:

You can add a helper column to identify the original NaNs:

```
out = (df
   .set_index(['id', 'month']).assign(flag=True)
   .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['id'].unique(),
                                        pd.date_range('2023-01-01', '2023-04-01', freq='MS')],
                                      names=['id', 'month']
                                      ))
   .groupby(level=0).ffill().loc[lambda d: d.pop('flag').notna()].reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
    id      month     value
0    1 2023-01-01    London
1    1 2023-02-01     Paris
2    1 2023-03-01     Paris
3    1 2023-04-01     Paris
4    2 2023-01-01  New York
5    2 2023-02-01  New York
6    2 2023-03-01  New York
7    2 2023-04-01  New York
8    3 2023-02-01     Paris
9    3 2023-03-01     Paris
10   3 2023-04-01     Paris
11   4 2023-03-01       NaN
12   4 2023-04-01       NaN
```

Comment: It seems to work, thank u! But just one problem: if I have a Null value on unique id, with this solution, the output hasn't the rows. I would anyway to explode month and keep Null on "value. I have updated my question with the id 4.

Thank u!

Comment: You can change a bit the logic of the second approach, see update